# prove that the sequence $x_{n+1} = \frac3{4-x_n}$ is converging and find its limit

Tags: calculus, limits

prove that this sequence is converging and find its limit

> $x_1 = \frac32$
>
> $x_{n+1} = \frac3{4-x_n}$

i believe that the solution entails proving the sequence is **monotone descending** and its **infimum** is 1, but i don't know to to show that.
i also tried messing with triangle inequality, but with no success so far
any help into solving this will be very appreciated

Comment: The supremum can't be $1$.

Comment: As a hint, try assuming that $1<x_n<1.5$ and see if you can prove that $1 < x_{n+1} < x_n$ for proving it is monotone, and bounded below by 1 (this doesn't prove the limit IS 1, though).

Comment: Contraction lemma, anybody?

Comment: It's not an exact duplicate $-$ it asks for the limit, which the earlier question doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x)=\frac3{4-x}$, so that $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Note that if $1<x<2$, then $3>4-x>2$, so $1<f(x)<\frac32$. Thus, $1<x_n\le\frac32$ for all $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. You’d like to show that $f(x)<x$ for $x\in\left(1,\frac32\right]$. When is it the case that

$$f(x)=\frac3{4-x}<x\;?\tag{1}$$

We’re interested only in $x\in\left(1,\frac32\right]$, so we may assume that $4-x>0$, in which case $(1)$ is equivalent to the inequality $3<4x-x^2$. Solve this inequality, and you’ll find that $f$ is a decreasing function on $\left(1,\frac32\right]$ and hence that $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is a monotonically decreasing sequence bounded below by $1$.

That proves that the sequence has a limit, say $L$, and it only remains to determine $L$. There’s a standard trick for this:

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=f(L)\;,$$

where the last step is justified by the fact that $f$ is continuous. Now just solve $f(L)=L$ for $L$, and you’ll have your limit.

Answer (score 0):

First, some motivation: If you sketch the curve of the function $f(x)=\frac{3}{4-x}$, you should see that it is convex on the interval $(1,\frac32]$. So each $x_{n+1}$ should be more than twice as close to $1$ as $x_n$ is.

So you should be trying to prove that $0 < x_{n+1} - 1 \le (x_n-1)/2$, which is enough to show convergence to $1$.

Comment: why would that prove that $L=1$?

Comment: @Jneven: Look at the last sentence of the first paragraph.

Comment: yes, why is this enough?